# Write-behind cache for .NET (free and simple)?

Tags: .net, asp.net, caching

I need simple and free **write-behind cache** for .NET. Does not have to be 100% reliable or fast. I have a growing website and I need something till Microsoft finally releases Velocity which should have write-behind in the near future.

- Do we have a simple write behind cache implementation for .NET?
- Do we have any .NET code samples on write-behind caching?

UPDATE

Please read the question carefully.

**WRITE-BEHIND CACHE**

Non any kind of cache. Not free version of NCache, not MemCached.

If you want to know what WRITE-BEHIND is - check [this Oracle article](http://wiki.tangosol.com/display/COH32UG/Read-Through,+Write-Through,+Refresh-Ahead+and+Write-Behind+Caching)

Answer (score 1):

[NCache Express](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) is free, We've used the express version and it's pretty decent.

Comment: NCache Express has very limited functionality. NCache Enterprise version - the only one version that has WRITE-BEHIND support - costs $4,000 per CPU.

Comment: I've used the Free version and built in my own WRITE-BEHIND to work with it - it's not that difficult to do, worth looking in to if you haven't got a suitable answer

Comment: Also to note if you are running the NCache on a VM the OS (Server 2003 in out case) assigns 1 virtual processor but a number of cores- which means if we did get an enterprise edition - only need one licence ;)

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with this, but I found two links you may be interested in:

[Cacheman](http://www.sriramkrishnan.com/blog/2008/02/cacheman-fast-distributed-hashtable-for.html) - distributed hashtable for Windows

[NMemcached](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/06/06/Scratching-an-itch-NMemcached.aspx) - somw throw away code from Ayende

You may to Google / investigate Memcached and see what you can find for .Net.  Sorry I don't have direct experience as I've just started the subject myself recently.

UPDATE:

I found this port of [memcache](http://jehiah.cz/projects/memcached-win32/) for .Net.  Here is an interesting blog [post](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2007/07/05/ASPNETCachingVsMemcachedSeekingEfficientDataPartitioningLookupAndRetrieval.aspx) concerning Asp.net cache vs memcache.  Good luck!!

Comment: Please, read the question closely... WRITE-BEHIND CACHE, not any kind of cache...